Curious about the collocation "unfettered access". What is its origin?
This is my "stocking stuffer" for the ELU community.  You might stumble upon something that gives you a  bit of joy when seeking an answer to the question.  I did.
The earliest attestation of the phrase "unfettered access" that I've found is in a sermon from the 1790s:

... a free and unfettered access to the sacred volumes of truth...

Was there something like "fettered access"? In order to see some personage, did you have to consent to be shackled?  Or had "unfettered" already entered the lexicon and lost its literal meaning of "unshackled" and simply become a synonym for "free"?

fetters is just a really old word for chains (more often used as a plural noun than a verb, I think). Which I didn't know until I just looked it up is cognate with Latin pedica - "chain for the feet". We also speak quite naturally of unrestricted access, but we wouldn't normally use unchained or unshackled access. Essentially, unfettered access is something of a "frozen form" that perhaps sounds grander than it really is.

Isn’t fettered access an oxymoron?

Not really.  You'd be led in in chains but still get to have an audience with the person.

Don't you think 'unfettered…' here means simply 'unrestricted…'?

@RobbieGoodwin  I don't think it's simple and straighttforward, as it would depend on the century of a work in which the word appears, and the genre of the work.

I think it's very simple and quite straightforward, until you show how it depends on century or genre… unless you're speculating…

Early occurrences of 'unfettered access' in the wild
The earliest match that a Google Books search for "unfettered access" turns up is from a sermon by Samuel Carr on Luke viii, 4–7, which appears in Samuel Carr, Sermons, on Practical Subjects, volume 2 (1795):

But if, with the infidel, we reject the word spoken ; or if, with the nominal Christian, we hear it with listless indifference ; or, if, with the speculative Christian, we receive it with joy, but come not under the vital energy and influence of it ; or lastly, if with the worldly Christian, we suffer it to be choked with cares, and riches, and pleasures ; we have much to fear from the just judgments of God, who has vouchsafed to us peculiar advantages over all the nations of the world, with respect to the knowledge of his will : a church, I will not say, infallible, or free from all corruptions ; but I will say, in the words of a wise and noble writer [Lord Clarendon], more free from dangerous corruptions, than any other that professes a faith in Christ : a ministry, in the confession of its enemies, not unlearned, or unable to feed the flock of Christ with wholesome doctrine ;  and, what is above all, a free and unfettered access to the sacred volumes of truth, with an unrestrained liberty of exercising that reason and judgment, which are the birth-right and honour of every reasonable creature.

This is evidently the instance that TimR refers to in his posted question. Carr, who was prebendary of Ealdstreet, St. Paul's, from 1776 until his death in 1794, produced sermons enough to fill three volumes of collected works. The sermon cited here appears near the end of volume 2, so it was probably delivered some time in the latter half of the 1780s (if the sermons are arranged chronologically).
The next-earliest Google Books matches for "unfettered acccess" appear in the 1830s. From "Suggestions Occasioned by the Clause of the Act of 3 and 4 William IV., Chap. LXXIII, Respecting the Apprenticeship of Negro Children," in The Anti-Slavery Monthly Reporter (December 26, 1833):

But there is, if possible, a still more weighty consideration involved in this question, and which cannot too strongly be pressed on the attention of every Christian, and especially of all Christian ministers and missionaries. One of the most potent instruments of success, in civilizing and christianizing the negro population, will be the free and unfettered access of the rising race to the means of education and religious instruction—the only means indeed of training them to knowledge and virtue.

And from "The Dissenters and the Universities," in Fraser's Magazine for Town and Country (August 1835):

Now our answer to this is, that, even under the existing state of things, Dissenters have at this moment a free and unfettered access to degrees in arts, law, medicine, and even divinity, in no fewer than four chartered universities of the British empire ; and this, without the slightest compromise either of creed or conscience.
...
Since Dissenters then, have free and unfettered access to institutions, whose excellent education is so cheap as to be peculiarly adapted to Dissenting circumstances, whose diplomas are so creditable and so efficient for all practical purposes, and whose exemption from theological tests presents such an entire neutrality on the subject of religious peculiarities, that the whole of the Scottish Dissenters, of every profession, are regularly educated at them, without scruple and without compromise,—surely in these circumstances, reflecting people will be very curious to know, to what extent the English Dissenters have made use of the advantages thus made to their hands, and thus inviting their acceptance.
...
On the other hand, if a large number be contended for, and conceded,—this would only shew, that the greater the extent to which they make use of their free and unfettered access to a sound, cheap, and liberal education in the northern universities, the stronger is the evidence that no practical grievance is suffered by them, from the existing constitution and usages of Oxford and Cambridge.


A closer look at 'free and unfettered'
As you probably noticed, all five unique instances of "unfettered access" in these three early sources occur as part of a longer phrase: "free and unfettered access." This raises the possibility that "free and unfettered" may be an older pairing than "unfettered access" is. Searches of Google Books and Early English Books Online confirm that this is indeed the case. The earliest matches for "free and unfettered" come from the 1600s.
From Thomas Jackson, Iustifying Faith: or The Faith by Which the Just Do Live (1631):

And that the former unaptnes in youth, especially to perceive truths morall or theologicall, doth not spring from any inherent dulnesse in the Intellective faculty, were the motions of it towards such points proposed free and unfettered ; is evident, in that their wits are in that age, for the most part sharpest, and able with ease to perceive the truth of such Mathematicall conclusions, as will hardly enter into riper judgemēts : much lesse doth this inconvenience spring from any faintnesse in their endeauours, for their spirits are most lively ; therefore onely from the abundance of affection or heat of passion, which secretly disswade their understandings from all acquaintence with such objects as are repugnant to themselves.

And from Peter Walsh, P. W's Reply to the Person of Quality's Answer Dedicated to His Grace, the Duke of Ormond (1664):

From the year 48 until the year 60. those this Gentlemans Protestants did indeed swim down the stream, and partake in the actings, and of the rewards of Cromwel. But then they did what became them, and merited a most benign interpretation from his Majesty of the duty which they had so early and so eminently performed. Yet let us not wholly deprive the people of England of the good effects of that influence, which their so publick expressions of their affections to the King, had upon Ireland likewise. And for the honour of those be it spoken, who with Oars and Sails made their way up the River, and would not hear of any restriction to be put upon the King, that all their fellows left not the Stream as willingly as they came to it; and that in the convention some men have been heard to speak of other matters than of bringing in the King free and unfettered.

The phrase "free and unfettered" appears fairly frequently in eighteenth-century publications, including a number of instances in which it appears in front of the noun that it modifies, as in "free and unfettered mind[s]" (1715, 1734, 1776), "free and unfettered discursions" (1775), "free and unfettered exercise [of religion]" (1778), "free and unfettered genius" (1783, 1793, 1794), "free and unfettered judgment" (1786, 1787, 1788), and "free and unfettered powers [of deliberation]" (1786). All of these instances antedate the print debut of "free and unfettered access" in 1795.
But if "unfettered access" is just a single hydra head grown from the body of "free and unfettered X," we face at least as baffling a puzzle as the one that TimR raised in the first place: why did people adopt the practice of saying "free and unfettered" rather than simply "free"? It is not the case that "free and unfettered" is one of those pairings out of English common law (like "will and testament") that originated as a way to thoroughly identify a concept by using synonyms from Saxon English and Norman French: both free and fetter arose from Old English roots.
One might argue that "free and unfettered" describes the result of a process in which someone is released from shackles and then set at liberty—but if so, the process is described backward, and we might logically expect it to be "unfettered and free." One early instance that follows that underlying progression appears in Edward Bagshaw, The Second Part of The Great Question Concerning Things Indifferent in Religious Worship Briefly Stated, and Tendred to the Consideration of All Conscientious and Sober Men (1661):

This is that which not only diffused, but so far fixed the fatal Poyson of Errour, that the world can never expect to be freed, till it pleases God to raise up some generous and truly Heroick Prince, who may be convinced of the truth of Christian Religion, not by hear-say from others, but by a through search and enquiry into the Causes of it himself, and growing from thence assured, that nothing can more hinder the Progress of the Gospel, then to dis∣guise and alter its simplicity (for a strange dress must needs render it suspected) will resolve to give it a free and undisturbed Passage, and never draw his Sword, but when Malice and Ignorance do joyn together, not only to oppose, but to persecute it; how will Truth then, being unfettered and set free, from the Clogges of pretended Decency, but indeed Antichristian Tyranny, run through this Nation, and chase Errour before it, as the Light doth Darkness?

That "free and unfettered" is a set phrase of long standing seems clear from the linked Ngram graph mapping the relative frequency of occurrence of "free and unfettered" (blue line) versus "unfettered access" (red line) in published writings in the Google Books database for the period 1600–2020.
The same Ngram graph also vividly describes the impressive rise in frequency of "unfettered access" over the past fifty years or so. I have no explanation for this development, but it clearly did not depend on a concomitant rise in usage of the longer form "free and unfettered access." Interestingly, Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) offers this very brief entry for unfettered:

unfettered adj (1601) FREE, UNRESTRAINED <unfettered access>

The first MW Collegiate Dictionary to accord a separate entry to unfettered as an adjective is the eighth edition (1973), and the first to include "unfettered access" as an example of the adjective in action is the eleventh edition (2003).

Conclusions
I strongly suspect that the set phrase "unfettered access" began as "free and unfettered access"—one of an array of "free and unfettered [noun]" phrases that proliferated in the late eighteenth century. In the past half-century, however, "unfettered access" has come into its own. It may be too soon to tell whether observers will someday categorize "unfettered access" as a cliche—along the lines of "unmitigated gall," "unsung hero," or "unvarnished truth"—but it has certainly reached a point in common usage where the two words go together easily and with minimal consideration of their individual parts.
